# block calls by area code in twilio laravel

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I just want to block call by area code like 404, 706 etc please let me know how to block twilio calls by area code. I have done block calls of specific number but i couldn't find the block calls by area code.

If anyone know please let me know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block outbound call by area code, check that the number you are attempting to dial is not in that area code before calling the Twilio [calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource).

Comment: I just want to block calls using voice response not for create calls. Please let me know if possible block incoming calls by area code.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, you need to create the logic. You use the TwiML `<Reject>` verb to do so, similar in concept to this article - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034792413-Reject-Incoming-Calls-with-a-Country-Blacklist.